# Websockets message loss

Tags: javascript, networking, websocket

When using websockets I noticed some message loss. I am trying to communicate between mobile safari (client) and c#(server). I am using superWebSocket (opensource) as a server, so it might be a server bug...

But the messages are only dropped when the connection is congested (When I send alot of messages). This "reaks" of UDP to me, but I remember reading somewhere that web-sockets are TCP.

Is there any occasion where I might issue a "send" command in javascript, and the receiving side does not get the message?

Comment: WebSockets are indeed TCP. This might be a browser issue or a server bug, but it's not UDP.

Comment: Your problem may not be a bug in browser.It may just the `normal` network problem you need handle. TCP can `lost` message, If the tcp connection break/reset. You can only know the peer see the message as you receive the ack from the peer in your protocol. And server first message can lost in websocket make this feeling worse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435420/1586797

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been using WebSockets extensively in with high traffic applications and in situations where a single lost message (in either direction) is fatal. I've never seen any messages lost, ever. However, I do recall seeing a post or question somewhere about the same issue and that person was also using superWebSocket for the server. So my strong suspicion is that there is a bug in superWebSocket.

Do you see the same problem if you use a non-mobile browser? It's possible the iOS brower (I assume that's what you mean by mobile Safari) has a WebSocket bug. I've not extensively tested that browser with WebSockets. I have extensively tested Chrome, Firefox (with WebSocket enabled), and Opera (with WebSocket enabled) on Linux and Windows and Safari on Windows.

There is no occasion where a send in Javascript is allowed to not reach the server except if the whole connection fails. If that is happening then there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: This question is very old. It refers to an old (obselete) websockets server, and iOs (3 or 4) when most mobile browsers did not implement websockets to begin with. I have never encountered the problem again.