# Prevent theoretical loss of the first received message in WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

Code on server-side sends a message *immediately* after connection is opened (it sends initial configuration/greetings to a client).

And the following code is on client-side:

```
var sock = new WebSocket(url);
sock.addEventListener('error', processError);
sock.addEventListener('close', finish);
sock.addEventListener('message', processMessage);
```

I worry about losing this first configuration/greetings-related message from server. Theoretically nothing prevents it from being received *before* `message` event handler is set.

On the other hand, practically it never occurred to me. And AFAIK JavaScript [WebSocket API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#the-websocket-interface) doesn't have countermeasures against this theoretical issue: the WebSocket [constructor](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#dom-websocket) neither allows `message` event handler to be set, nor allows WebSocket to be created in suspended state.

So:

1. Either I am missing something, and loss of message with the above code is impossible even theoretically.
2. Or it is bug in JavaScript WebSocket API design.
3. Or everyone is just happy because message loss is *practically* impossible.
4. Or such behavior (sending message from server on connection) is somewhy considered bad practice, so no one bothers about possibility to implement it theoretically correct.

?

<sub>P.S.: Do such simple-but-theoretical questions better fit [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Programmers@Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?</sub>

Comment: Since the language is single-threaded, I would expect provided functionality to also be single-threaded. Don't take my word for it, but most probably `WebSocket` does not start operating until the main thread is free to work.

Comment: @odyss-jii: JavaScript is not single-threaded. The language has next to nothing to say about threading. Browsers run one main UI thread, and as many web-workers as you want. Other environments (Rhino, Nashorn) run JavaScript multi-threaded.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Whilst that is true, it would be terrible design. If `WebSocket` implementation is such that it auto-connects on creation and does not provide a way of registering listeners before connecting, then it is seriously flawed.

Comment: Sasha, MDN is a great resource, but it's not *the spec*. The current spec is [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#the-websocket-interface). I'm running out the door, but I'd read that carefully to see when and where it starts listening for messages, in particular if it talks about "queuing a task" (or enqueuing a job, to use JS parlance) to do so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the img load case is a bit different, since in the cached resource case the callback is invoked *synchronously* (I worked on the Chrome DevTools a while ago and looked into that particular case), which should never be the case for WebSockets...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I think you're wrong about the multi-threading issue. The Websocket is initiated within a single threaded loop. Even when there are many different single-threaded loops, such as with browsers and web-workers , the websocket itself is "owned" by that single threaded loop and it will not be opened until that same loop processes the websocket opening event (the one scheduled by `new WebSocket(...)`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: It need not be synchronous. All that's required is for the event to be raised by the network layer, the browser to see no `load` callbacks, and thus not queue a task for an event callback.

Comment: @Myst: I never said the `WebSocket` wasn't associated with a single thread. I said browsers are not single-threaded.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - The browser doesn't check for the callbacks, the event loop does. This is why no events can be lost even if the callback isn't defined until later on in the code.  There is no possibility for messages to be lost just because you're code didn't finish running before the first message entered the task queue.

Comment: @Myst: Yes, in the web sockets case, that is exactly the case -- and your answer is entirely correct about web sockets. (It may well be true that since the HTML5 clarified some things, browsers aren't allowed to do what they used to with `img`s, either.)

Comment: Sasha, I was going to post an answer, but Myst's already covers it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thanks for the edits to my answer - nicely done!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Just to back Myst with some material (and give others a bit of insight of the internals): with Chromium, "the renderer's only access to the network is via its parent browser process" (https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture), and the two processes interact with each other by means of IPC, each of its queues being handled by the respective process event loop.

Comment: @Myst: My pleasure. It was already correct and reasonably clear, but I thought the quotes would help.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: Right, again, the web sockets part of the HTML5 specification makes it clear the OP's concern can't happen. But it's not because JavaScript is single-threaded, it's because the web sockets spec ensures that responding to an event queues a task *without* first checking for handlers. That's the crucial difference. My comment at the top wasn't meant to say "browsers will do this," it was meant to say that a simplistic "nah, can't, coz JS is single-threaded" is not an adequate answer. Myst's answer is.

Comment: I've removed my first comment above, since this now has a correct answer that *isn't* just the knee-jerk "Nah, can't, coz JS is single-threaded" that you usually see. :-) (And I think that comment could easily be misread.)

Comment: Your theory is real. Looks like I actually got into this bug.  I write an app that open a websocket on http to 127.0.0.1 golang server. My server send serval messages first to the app. And the first serval messages may lost and may not lost.I think the server must wait client first message then send message to client. I use chrome 62 on gce 1 cpu 3.75GB memory ubuntu 1404 . This bug do not happened on my mac chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't worry.

Your code is running within a single threaded event loop.

This line: `var sock = new WebSocket(url);` doesn't initiate a websocket connection at all. [The spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#the-websocket-interface) says that it must perform the actual connection only after returning the web socket, in parallel with the thread handling the event loop your code is running on:

> 8. Return a new WebSocket object, but continue these steps [in parallel][2].

That alone wouldn't be sufficient, but all subsequent `WebSocket` events for that socket are scheduled inside the *same* single-threaded event loop that is running your code. Here's what the spec says about receiving a message:

> When a WebSocket *message has been received* with type *type* and data *data*, the user agent must *queue a task* to follow these steps

That task is queued on the same event loop. That means that the task to process the message **cannot** be run until the task where you created your `WebSocket` has run to completion. So your code will finish running before the event loop will process any connection related messages.

Even if you're running your code in a browser that uses many threads, the specific code will run on a single threaded event loop and each event loop will be independent.

Different event loops can and do communicate by pushing tasks into each other's task-queues. But these tasks will be executed within the single-threaded event-loop that received the task, keeping your code thread-safe.

The task "handle this event" will be handled by the single threaded event loop finding the appropriate event handler and calling its callback... but this will only happen once the task is already being handled.

To be clearer:

I'm not claiming that each event-loop actually handles the IO - but the IO scheduler will send your code events and these events will run sequentially within a single thread (sort of, they do have priority management that uses different "task queues").

#### EDIT: client code concerns

It should be noted that the Websocket API wasn't designed for the DOM's function `addEventListener`.

Instead, the Websocket API follows the HTML4 paradigm, where event callbacks are object properties (rather than the EventListener collection). i.e.:

```
// altered DOM API:
sock.addEventListener('message', processMessage);
// original WebSocket API:
sock.onmessage = processMessage;
```

Both APIs work correctly on all the browsers I tested (including safe delivery of first message). The difference in approaches is probably handled by the HTML4 compatibility layer.

However the specification regarding event scheduling is different, so the use of `addEventListener` should probably be avoided.

#### EDIT 2 : Testing the Theory

Regarding [Bronze Man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435420/4025095) concerning failed message responses...

I couldn't reproduce the claimed issue, even though I wrote a test using a small Ruby application and a small Javascript Client.

The Ruby application starts up a Websocket echo server with a welcome message (I'm using [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io)).

The Javascript client contains a busy-wait loop that causes the Javascript thread to hang (block) for the specified amount of time (2 seconds in my tests).

The `onmessage` callback is set only after the block is released (after 2 seconds) - so the welcome message from the server will arrive at the browser before the callback is defined.

This allows us to test if the welcome message is lost on any specific browser (which would be a bug in the browser).

The test is reliable since the server is a known quantity and will send the message to the socket as soon as the `upgrade` is complete (I wrote the Iodine server backend in C as well as the plezi.io framework and I chose them because of my deep knowledge of their internal behavior).

The Ruby application:

```
# run from terminal using `irb`, after `gem install plezi`
require 'plezi'
class WebsocketEcho
    def index
       "Use Websockets"
    end
    def on_message data
       # simple echo
       write data
    end
    def on_open
       # write a welcome message
       # will ths message be lost?
       write "Welcome to the WebSocket echo server."
       puts "New Websocket connection opened, welcome message was sent."
    end
end
# adds mixins to the class and creates route
Plezi.route("/", WebsocketEcho)

# running the server from the terminal
Iodine.threads = 1
Iodine::Rack.app = Plezi.app
Iodine.start
```

The Javascript Client:

```
function Client(milli) {
    this.ws = new WebSocket("ws" + window.document.location.href.slice(4, -1));
    this.ws.client = this;
    this.onopen = function (e) { console.log("Websocket opened", e); }
    this.ws.onopen = function (e) { e.target.client.onopen(e); }
    this.onclose = function (e) { console.log("Websocket closed", e); /* reconnect? */ }
    this.ws.onclose = function (e) { e.target.client.onclose(e); }
    if(milli) { // busy wait, blocking the thread.
        var start = new Date();
        var now = null;
        do {
            now = new Date();
        } while(now - start < milli);
    }
    this.onmessage = function (e) { console.log(e.data); }
    // // DOM API alternative for testing:
    // this.ws.addEventListener('message', function (e) { e.target.client.onmessage(e); });
    // // WebSocket API for testing:
    this.ws.onmessage = function (e) { e.target.client.onmessage(e); }    
}
// a 2 second window
cl = new Client(2000);
```

Results on my machine (MacOS):

- Safari 11.01 initiates the Websocket connection only after the new client was creation is complete (after the thread is done processing the code, as indicated by the Ruby application's delayed output). The message obviously arrived once the connection was made.
- Chrome 62.0 initiates the Websocket connection immediately. The message arrives once the 2 second window ends. Message wasn't lost even though it arrived before the `onmessage` handler was set.
- FireFox 56.0 behaves the same as Chrome, initiating the Websocket connection immediately. The message arrives once the 2 second window ends. Message wasn't lost.

If someone could test on Windows and Linux, that would be great... but I don't think the browsers will have implementation issues with the event scheduling. I believe the specifications can be trusted.

Comment: [Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#dom-websocket) says: "When the WebSocket() constructor is invoked, the UA must run these steps: [...] 8. Return a new WebSocket object, but continue these steps [in parallel](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel). [...] 10. [Establish a WebSocket connection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#concept-websocket-establish) [...]". Doesn't this prove that you are wrong?

Comment: This mainly proves that I'm not so good at explaining... I'm trying to fix my answer so it's clearer. The question of the IO running in a different event-loop isn't important, because your event loop will not handle new events until after your code had finished... so your event handler will only be reviewed **after** the code finished setting everything up.

Comment: @Sasha: That's half of it. The other half is how receiving a message is handled. Crucially, it's handled by scheduling a task on the same event loop. Since that task can't be processed until the previous task (creating the `WebSocket` and initiating the parallel connection operation) has been finished, you won't miss messages.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks. Your additions are really important.

Comment: The theory is real. The first client receive message can be lost. And the message can more then one.

Comment: @bronzeman I updated the answer to reflect your concerns. Please review and let me know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your theory is true and real.

I ACTUALLY got into this situation on chrome 62 on ubuntu 1404 when my chrome extension background page open a websocket connection to 127.0.0.1 server. My server send serval messages first to the app. And the first serval messages may lost and may not lost. But this bug do not happen on my mac chrome 62. I think this is what data race looks like.It may never happen, but it may happen in theory. So we need to prevent it happen.

Here is my client code looks like:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
var lastConnectTime = new Date();
ws.onerror = processError;
ws.onclose = finish;
ws.onmessage = processMessage;
```

**Solution**

The solution should be the server must wait client first message(even if it do not have any information) then send message to client.

Here is my solution in client js in code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
var lastConnectTime = new Date();
ws.onerror = processError;
ws.onclose = finish;
ws.onmessage = processMessage;
ws.onopen = function(){
   ws.send("{}");
};
```

Here is my solution in golang server:

```
func (s *GoServer)ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("WebsocketServeHttp recv connect",r.RemoteAddr)
    conn,err:=websocket.Upgrade(w,r,nil,10240,10240)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    _,_,err=conn.ReadMessage()
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    //... (you can send message to the client now)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, but from [Myst+T.J. Crowder](//stackoverflow.com/a/34900879) it seems that such situation can't occur even in theory. Are you sure that the messages are really lost? Does message loss still occur if you move the client code from the extension background page to the usual html-page? (P.S.: Chrome or Chromium? Does Chromium also lose messages? And Firefox?)

Comment: Sounds like a possible browser issue. However, I would also reconsider the client code, since [`addEventListener` has different specification requirements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-flow) than setting the callback directly (`sock.onmessage = processMessage`). This could effect the way in which event scheduling occurs.

Comment: @Sasha, I updated my answer due to the concerns shown here. After reading the specifications and following some testing, it seems it might be the client code that uses the wrong API (`addEventListener ` is the DOM API and `ws.onmessage = function(e) {/*...*/};` seems to be the correct Websocket API... but I'm not sure because all my browsers worked as expected.

Comment: @Sasha how do you know that the websocket can conntected between new WebSocket and ws.onmessage? In my options, `in parallel` means everything possible event order can happen.

Comment: @Myst I actually use `ws.onmessage = function(e) {/*...*/};` I had edited my code in the answer.

Comment: bronze man, I edited my answer to provide a testing application (both server and client code). I can verify that none of the browsers I could test had an issue. I would recommend that you run the tests against your browser. Note that this might be a server code issue as well. Please let the community know what you discover! Thanks!

Comment: @Myst, I don't believe that that's due to using of `addEventListener` instead of `onmessage`. IMHO, that's either bronze man's mistake (effect is caused by some other part of his code), or the effect of a browser bug (maybe related to  specific browser version/use-cases). Bronze man said this happens in the **extension background** page (I'd recommend him to put the same code into usual HTML page — maybe Chrome "optimizes" extension pages — and to test different browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox) —— to precise the area/conditions where the effect occurs.)

Comment: @bronzeman, have you tried to use a **Go** client (with the same Go server)? Maybe it's a server issue. (I.e. maybe other (Go-based, not JavaScript-based) client will also miss first server messages.)

Comment: @Sasha, I believe you're right. I suspect it might be a server/client issue and this is why I added the testing code that will test the browser. As for the `addEventListener`, both approaches work on all the browsers I tested on... however, reading the specification implies a difference in the scheduling and event handling design. Since the Websocket isn't part of the DOM tree than it's really unclear how the difference in the specification would effect this use. I don't think there's a point in using the DOM API (with a different specification) instead of the actual Websocket API.

Comment: I'm seeing the bug too, and it seems like a browser bug. I dug deeper into it, and posted my observations into a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411315/328565

Answer (score 3):

Confirming that the problem does exist (as a rare but real situation) on Chrome 62 and 63 on Ubuntu: occasional loss of first message from server. I confirmed with tcpdump that there is indeed a handshake packet and then the packet for the first message. In the client, the first message even shows up in the Networking tab as a first frame on the websocket. Then `onopen` callback is called, but `onmessage` is NOT.

I agree that it doesn't seem possible, and looking at WebKit's implementation of WebSocket, it doesn't seem possible, and I've never seen it on Chrome Mac or in Firefox, so my only guess is that Chrome on Ubuntu introduced a race condition with some optimization.

Comment: Chrome only, or Chromium too?

Comment: Thanks for your comfirm. I do not dig into this problem after I found a stable workaround to this bug. So I think the document is not the real code.The real code may have bugs and data race, and the document may also have bugs. The document and the real code may not have the same exactly behave.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely lose messages! The accepted answer is misleading. All that has to happen is that you do an operation that relinquishes the thread of control between the open event and configuring a message listener.

Is that likely to happen? Who knows, it depends on your application. Here's the situation that led me to waste too much time debugging this (the api sucks!) using the ws library on the server:

On the server:

```
async handleOpen(socket, request) {
  const session = await getSession(cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie).id);
  const user = new User(session.user.id, socket);
  user.socket.addEventListener('message', this.handleMessage.bind(this, user));
}
```

See that `await`? That relinquishes control and allows events to be lost. For what it's worth, the session was stored in memcached so was not immediately available.

Comment: But you do `await` here (between `socket` creation and `socket.addEventListener(…)`). My question was about much more simple case. In no way your answer denies the Myst's answer, but I thank you for additional details.

Comment: True, but googling led me to this question, so hopefully anyone else facing a similar problem will have an easier time.